# WebHeaderCollection.Add()の正確な設定方法が知りたい

Tags: c#

提示コードですが以下のマストドンサイトのAPIでjsonを得るのコードなのですがなぜ`///`コメント内部のコードで例外が発生するのでしょうか？原因がわかりません。

色々調べたことによるとURLには問題はなくサーバーが自分のリクエストを弾いてることが問題のようで`user-agent`を設定したように今回も似たような設定が必要と考えて
`WebHeaderCollection.Add()`に値を設定したいのですがどれも例外が発生してしまいます。これはどうやって値を設定するのでしょうか？

###### 例外メッセージ

リモート サーバーがエラーを返しました: (403) 使用不可能

###### 試したこと

URLのリダイレクトURIを書き換える
リファレンスサイトを確認
`"http://www.google.co.jp/"`の場合は４０３が発生せずコードが実行できます
リクエストヘッダーサイトを参考に`req.Headers.Set`をにいろいろ値を設定しましたがどれも例外が発生します。

###### ソースコード

参考サイトのリファレンスから`OAuth2 資格情報を取得するための新しいアプリケーションを作成します。`
のjsonを得るコードです。

###### 参考サイト

リファレンス: https://docs.joinmastodon.org/methods/apps/
GetResponece(): https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.getresponse?view=net-7.0
エラーサイト：https://www.innovation.co.jp/urumo/http_error/
リクエストヘッダー: https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Glossary/Request_header

###### 提示コード

```cs
        private static async Task test_run()
        {            

            
//            var req = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.co.jp/");
            var req = WebRequest.Create("https://mstdn.jp/api/v1/timelines/public");
            //var req = WebRequest.Create("https://mstdn.jp/api/v1/apps?client_name=test&redirect_uris=https%3A%2F%2Fmstdn.jp%2Fauth%2Fsign_in");
            //var req = WebRequest.Create("https://mstdn.jp/api/v1/apps?client_name=test&redirect_uris=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob");

            
            Console.WriteLine("aaaaaa");
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //req.Headers.Set("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko");
            //req.Headers.Set("Host","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko");
            //req.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko");
            req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language:ja,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3");


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            try
            {
                var res = req.GetResponse();
            }catch(System.Net.WebException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            Console.WriteLine("bbbbbb");

            Console.ReadKey();
            /*
            // レスポンス(JSON)をオブジェクトに変換
            ServiceResult info;
            using (res)
            {
                using (var resStream = res.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ServiceResult));
                    info = (ServiceResult)serializer.ReadObject(resStream);
                }
            }
            */

            Console.ReadKey();



        }


        private static async void test()
        {
            Task.WaitAll(test_run());

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           // t();

            test();



        }


        [DataContract]
        public class ServiceResult
        {

            [DataMember]
            public string id { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string name { get; set; }

        }
```

Comment: 問題が再現する最小限のコードまで落とし込んだ質問にしてみてはいかがでしょう。

Comment: はい。最小限のコードにしたのですがなぜか例外が発生します。

Comment: 関係無いかもしれませんが、こんな知識の記事があるので何か参考になるかもしれません。[非同期処理、なにもわからない](https://www.kekyo.net/2021/02/24/7268)

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみましたが以下の例外が発生します。`System.Net.WebException: 'リモート サーバーがエラーを返しました: (403) 使用不可能'
`

Comment: こんな記事があるので何か参考になるかもしれません。[IFTTTをつかってMastodonへトゥート](https://www.storange.jp/2021/12/toot-with-ifttt.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます。その後いろいろ調べたのですがどうやらサーバーがリクエストを弾いてるみたいなのですがこの部分はどうやって設定すればいいのしょうか？https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.net.webheadercollection.add?view=net-7.0#system-net-webheadercollection-add(system-string-system-string)

Comment: こんな記事と同様に手作業で確かめてみるとかどうでしょう？ [Mastodon API の叩き方](https://gist.github.com/okapies/eab5c6fc217e914ed0cac6c944384e4d), [MastodonAPIの仕様など](https://gist.github.com/mimikun/890e69a6ace3f48581e464cc6fe380c3), [mstdn.jpのアプリケーションのユーザー認証](https://o-treetree.hatenablog.com/entry/2021/03/19/223255) こちらはJavaで組んだようですが [AndroidアプリでHTTP通信(POST)](https://o-treetree.hatenablog.com/entry/2021/03/19/110828) あとは削除された質問関連でmastodon.cloudに接続する記事とか。[Mastodon のクライアントアプリを .NET Core で作ってみた](https://qiita.com/amay077/items/862d3228ac090be1d4fe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[403 Forbidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403)は<del>認証エラー</del>認可エラーです。質問のコードには認証認可に関する処理が含まれていないので、何を指定しても認可エラーになるのは当然の結果です。逆に認可を必須としていないGoogleでエラーにならないのも当然です。

[Logging in with an account](https://docs.joinmastodon.org/client/authorized/) に従い、認証および認可の処理を済ませてから実行してください。

> ### Client ID and secret
>
> First, if you have not already registered a client application, then see Creating our application on the previous page or go directly to POST /api/v1/apps for the full documentation of that method. We will need the `client_id` and `client_secret` for our application.

とあり、内容を読んでいないと `/api/v1/apps` を呼び出し可能と思われるかもしれませんが、このAPIを呼び出すためにも認証処理が必要です。鶏と卵状態であり、それを解決するための方法が「see Creating our application on the previous page」なわけです。

登録が済んだら`client_id`（クライアントキー）と`client_secret`（クライアントシークレット）を入手できているはずですので、Authorize the user以降の手順を実施してください。

---

> var req = WebRequest.Create("https://mstdn.jp/api/v1/apps?client_name=test&redirect_uris=https%3A%2F%2Fmstdn.jp%2Fauth%2Fsign_in");を実行しても依然として403エラーが発生するのですがはやり何か別の何かだと思うのですがどうなのでしょうか？

は「内容を読んでいないと `/api/v1/apps` を呼び出し可能と思われるかもしれませんが、このAPIを呼び出すためにも認証処理が必要です。」と書いた通りです。回答をよく読んでください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問ですが`var req = WebRequest.Create("https://mstdn.jp/api/v1/apps?client_name=test&redirect_uris=https%3A%2F%2Fmstdn.jp%2Fauth%2Fsign_in");`を実行しても.GetResponse()で依然として403エラーが発生するのですがはやり何か別の何かだと思うのですがどうなのでしょうか？実装したリクエスト: https://docs.joinmastodon.org/methods/apps/#create-an-application

Comment: 実装コード: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xxwCIV

Comment: えっと「認証処理が必要です」よね。 client_id と client_secret が必要なのでは？

Comment: YumaInaura 稲浦悠馬 氏　はいweb上の開発ページがクライアントキー、クライアントシークレット、アクセストークンを取得したのですがどうやって認証するのでしょうか？このサイトを見ましたがcurlコマンドのやり方しか乗っておらずわかりません。 
https://docs.joinmastodon.org/client/token/#app

Comment: @samidare_chan そういう質問を書いてもらえれば回答は可能です。

Comment: (質問の本題から逸れた話になってしまうのですが) `403 Forbidden` は認証ではなく認可のエラーだと思います。[原文](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403)では "refuses to authorize it" とありますので、[日本語](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403)の "認証が拒否された" は誤訳でしょう(認証なら "authenticate"; [PR](https://github.com/mdn/translated-content/pull/9900))。

Comment: @DEWAKazuyuki-出羽和之 ご指摘ありがとうございます。確かに本題からは脱線しますが、OAuthにおいては重要なことなので訂正しました。ユーザー自身がサービスの認証を行うこと、ユーザーがアプリケーションを認可すること、ここが明確に分かれますね。